# Is it possible to read .mat files in Go?

Tags: go, mat-file

I'd like to load a MATLAB file that stores a 1x1 struct with 4 fields using Go. I haven't found anything comparable to Python's SciPy which has a "[loadmat](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html)" function. What is the best way to read .mat files in Go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have to write your own Go package. MathWorks suggests that you interface with their MATLAB MAT-file C API. To do that in Go, use cgo.

References:

[MATLAB MAT-File Format - MathWorks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matfile_format.pdf)

[Command cgo](http://golang.org/cmd/cgo/)

[C? Go? Cgo!](http://blog.golang.org/c-go-cgo)

Answer (score 1):

No, there doesn't seem to be any project for reading MalLab files in pure Go (in CGo, see [PeterSO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/221700/peterso)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26553887/6309)):

- [go-search](http://go-search.org/search?q=matlab) doesn't list any relevant project
- [GitHub](https://github.com/search?l=go&q=matlab&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93) doesn't have any either.
- the [Libraries list](http://go-lang.cat-v.org/pure-go-libs) doesn't include any

And, there were performance consideration as well, mentioned in "[Go matrix library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16536029/6309)".
The [discussion was more about calling go from Matlab](http://grokbase.com/p/gg/golang-nuts/1492bd4vkm/go-nuts-matlab-interface).